# Set value of string in variable

Tags: bash

I want to set FOO="myvar" and set myvar to another variable. Not sure if that makes sense. Example below.

```
FOO="myvar"
BAR="true true false"
eval $FOO=$BAR    <==== Problem line
echo $myvar
```

I want the last line to print "true true false"

Comment: 1) `$mayvar` isn't defined anywhere ..  2) if this is straight `bash` --  lose the `eval $` and just set `FOO=$BAR` if you are in fact trying to set `FOO = BAR` or in plain words *FOO is equal to BAR*

Comment: myvar is the string in $FOO. I want to create a variable with the name of $FOO with the contents of $BAR

Comment: then should you no be echoing `$FOO`  --  NOT `$myvar` (which is a string not a variable name)?  I am confused.

Comment: `echo "${!myvar}"` is an indirect lookup. Which we already have existing Q&A for.

Comment: @Zak `eval $FOO=$BAR` expands to `eval myvar=true true false`, which, if quoted properly, would then perform the desired assignment to the name `myvar`.

Comment: I want FOO to be expanded to myvar. I then want to set myvar equal to bar. "myvar" is passed into a function and I don't know when it is in advance.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon, yes, that's indirect assignment and expansion. Look under that name and you'll find *lots* of entries already in the knowledgebase.

Comment: ...it's also very extensively documented in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon, ...btw, see [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) re: why answers using `eval` are frowned on. (It's *possible* to use safely, but requires a lot of care both when writing and when auditing code for security, which is why newer/safer constructs are preferred instead).

Comment: Much appreciated. I had no idea what it was called.

Comment: (btw, (1) all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment and shell variables share a namespace; (2) if `true true false` is meant to be a list of separate items, it's generally good practice to use an array instead of a string).